# Declare php variables by for loop in array

Tags: php, arrays

How to declare variables in the array using for loop. I have 3 input fields on my page, so when the submit buttons is pressed, it should process the following line of code. On my html page, there are fields named: question1, question2, and question3.

Here's the code of process.php file. It doesn't work for some reason, I suppose there are several mistakes here but I cannot find em.

```
<?php

$question = array();
for($j=1; $j<4; $j++) {
    $question[j] = $_POST['question[j]'];

$result;
$n=1;

if($question[j] != "") {
    $result = $n.'): '.$question[j].'<br/><br/>';
    $n++;
}
}

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Variable names should be prefixed with a `$`. Your literal `j` will be interpreted as constant. Enable `error_reporting` whenever things don't work.

Comment: And for accessing a list of input fields, it's advisable to use the array name syntax in your HTML forms: `<input name=question[1] ..>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$question = array();
$result = "";

for($j=1; $j<4; j++) {
    $question[$j] = $_POST["question$j"];

    if($question[$j] != "") {
        $result .= $j.'): '.htmlentities($question[$j]).'<br/><br/>';
    }
}

echo $result;

?>
```

Though you don't need an array.

```
<?php
$result = "";

for($j=1; $j<4; j++) {
    $result .= $_POST["question$j"]!="" ? htmlentities($_POST["question$j"]).'<br/><br/>':'';        
}

echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, arrays are zero-indexed, so I think you want this:

```
for($j=0; $j<3; j++)
```

Aside form that, this doesn't evaluate the value of `j`:

```
$_POST['question[j]']
```

I think you might want something like this:

```
$_POST["question$j"]
```

**However**, if you made the indexing change above, since your elements are named starting with 1 instead of 0 then you'd need to account for that:

```
$_POST['question' . $j+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="question[a]" />
<input type="text" name="question[b]" />
<input type="text" name="question[c]" />
```

with following PHP code:

```
foreach($_POST["question"] as $key => $value)
{
    // $key == "a", "b" or "c"
    // $value == field values
}
```

Remember to sanitize Your input!